# how to set django database request timeout for oracle

Tags: python-2.7, oracle11g, django-1.8

I want to set timeout for a database request so that it can handle for some requests blocked abnormally long time.

I tried first below configuration with `connect_timeout` attribute.

```
DATABASES = {
             'default': {
                         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
                         'NAME': 'orcl',
                         'USER': 'smkim',
                         'PASSWORD': '1123',
                         'HOST': '168.192.15.18',
                         'OPTIONS' : {
                                      "connect_timeout": 60,
                                      },
                         'CONN_MAX_AGE' : 60,
                         'PORT': '1521',
                         }
             }
```

However, it seems not to work returning this exception.

> TypeError: 'connect_timeout' is an invalid keyword argument for this
>   function

Additionally, it is not the thing I want since the attribute(`connect_timeout`) seems to be for only connection.
(In my case, it will have persistent connections)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it through the oracle client setting on `sqlnet.ora` rather than on `Django`.

```
SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT = 10  # in seconds
SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT = 10  # in seconds
```

So that Django return `djang.db.DatabaseError` Exception with oracle error code when it reaches the timeout I specify(in here 10 sec)

You can get the oracle error code like below

```
try:
   models.A.objects.get(id=1)  # In here, timeout occur

except django.db.DatabaseError as e:
   oracleErr = e.args[0]
   print 'errorMsg  : %s' % oracleErr.message
   print 'errorCode : %d' % oracleErr.code
```